# Scaling problem with fontspec package and \footnote.

Tags: xetex, footnotes, fontspec, scaling

footnote does not scale properly with using fontspec. Any idea how to solve this problem? Already tried realscripts and xltxtra but no luck.
Thanks,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\newcommand{\phont}[1]{\fontspec[Scale=#1]{Times New Roman}} 

\begin{document}\noindent 

{\phont{1} test\footnote{test}}\\ 
{\phont{2} test\footnote{test}}\\ 
{\phont{3} test\footnote{test}}\\ 
{\phont{1}test\textsuperscript{1}}\\ 
{\phont{2}test\textsuperscript{2}}\\ 
{\phont{3}test\textsuperscript{3}} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's "by design". LaTeX's `\footnote` sets its footnote mark in font `\normalfont`. However you want the current text font. `\textsuperscript` keeps the current font except the font size.

The behaviour of LaTeX can be changed by redefining `\@makefnmark`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\phont}[1]{\fontspec[Scale=#1]{Times New Roman}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makefnmark}{%
  \hbox{%
    \@textsuperscript{%
      % \normalfont % removed
      \selectfont % added
      \@thefnmark
    }%
  }%  
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}

\noindent
{\phont{1} test\footnote{test}}\\
{\phont{2} test\footnote{test}}\\
{\phont{3} test\footnote{test}}\\
{\phont{1}test\textsuperscript{1}}\\
{\phont{2}test\textsuperscript{2}}\\
{\phont{3}test\textsuperscript{3}}  

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]