# make footnote number appear next to chapter title

Tags: footnotes, chapters

I would like a footnote number to appear right next to a chapter title (instead of below it) to cite a co-author of this particular chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{hello}\footnote{another author}
\end{document}
```

This puts the number 1 below the title of the chapter. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to be careful of what might end up in the ToC. As such, use a different optional argument for `\chapter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[hello]{hello\footnote{another author}}

\end{document}
```

If you want something that's a little more subtle, you could use:

[image]

```
\chapter[hello]{hello\raisebox{.3\baselineskip}{\normalsize\footnotemark}}
\footnotetext{another author}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on the ToC thing? What is the optional argument to chapter do? Sorry all things I could look up but I'm hours prior to my deadline : )

Comment: @Alex: If you say `\chapter{My Title}`, the string “My Title” is used both for the title of the chapter and for the line in the ToC that points to it; if you say `\chapter[My Title 1]{My Title 2}`, then “My Title 2” is used for the title, and “My Title 1” for the line in the ToC.  In this case, you want to footnote the chapter title, but *not* its associated line in the ToC, therefore…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: thanks very much, make sense!

Comment: @Werner: could you just elaborate on the answer a bit.. what `\raisebox` is doing, just so i'm clear on what's actually happening rather than copy pasting your working solution. that would be very helpful, if possible.

Comment: @Alex: The size of the footnote number is huge when used as-is within the `\chapter` title. You could make it a little less intrusive to the eyes by using a different font size. However, for ease of use `{<fontsize>\footnotemark}` doesn't raise the footnote high enough, as the surround text is set at `\huge` (by default). So, you may have to raise it into place a little better, and that's where the `\raisebox{<height>}` comes in. You could fiddle with the actual `\footnotemark` macro, but my suggestion is just an easy alternative.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72803/scaling-problem-with-fontspec-package-and-footnote and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193929/same-footnotemark-size-all-over-the-document for the size of the footnote mark

Comment: thanks very much for all your help. this looks very nice